# Coloring cell text makes tabularx add undesired vertical space

Tags: tables, color, tabularx

I know that I must not use vertical rules but I'm trying to reproduce a SAS output like this:

[image]

When I use a simple `tabular` my code works well (see the first table below), but when I use one or more `X` column from `tabularx` some undesired vertical space appears (see the 2nd and the 3rd tables below).

What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newcommand{\stilecomandoa}{\color{blue!60!black}\bfseries}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|>{\stilecomandoa}r|l|l|r|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\stilecomandoa Alphabetic List of Variables and Attributes}\\      
            \hline
            \# & {\stilecomandoa Variable} & {\stilecomandoa Type} & {\stilecomandoa Len} \\
            \hline
            3 & Age & Num & 8 \\
            \hline
            4 & Height & Num & 8 \\
            \hline
            1 & Name & Char & 8 \\
            \hline
            2 & Sex & Char & 1 \\
            \hline
            5 & Weight & Num & 8 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}    
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabularx}{.7\linewidth}{|>{\stilecomandoa\arraybackslash}X|X|X|X|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\stilecomandoa Alphabetic List of Variables and Attributes}\\      
            \hline
            \# & {\stilecomandoa Variable} & {\stilecomandoa Type} & {\stilecomandoa Len} \\
            \hline
            3 & Age & Num & 8 \\
            \hline
            4 & Height & Num & 8 \\
            \hline
            1 & Name & Char & 8 \\
            \hline
            2 & Sex & Char & 1 \\
            \hline
            5 & Weight & Num & 8 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabularx}{.7\linewidth}{|>{\stilecomandoa\arraybackslash}r|X|X|r|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{\stilecomandoa Alphabetic List of Variables and Attributes}\\      
            \hline
            \# & {\stilecomandoa Variable} & {\stilecomandoa Type} & {\stilecomandoa Len} \\
            \hline
            3 & Age & Num & 8 \\
            \hline
            4 & Height & Num & 8 \\
            \hline
            1 & Name & Char & 8 \\
            \hline
            2 & Sex & Char & 1 \\
            \hline
            5 & Weight & Num & 8 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}   
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it's a documented feature (use `\leavevmode` before `\color`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ops, I didn't read the documentation!

Comment: `texdoc grfguide`  footnote on page 6

Comment: note it's not using tabularx that is the problem, it is changing `l` to `p` column type